# Passing java arguments using weblogic startup using java program

Tags: solr, weblogic, startup

I want to pass two parameters to web-logic startup like below using java code.
export

```
SOLR_ZK_CREDS_AND_ACLS="-DzkDigestUsername=admin -DzkDigestPassword=admin123 \"
```

as above string shows password as a plain text i need to pass it using java program where I will handle encryption/decryption for same.

What has been tried.
 Added a Servlet loader classs in **web-xml** and set `System.setProperty` but still its not getting picked up by weblogic.

Please suggest something.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to set them from the console under Server Start?

1. Navigate to Weblogic console
2. Click on Servers (you can find it under Environment > Servers)
3. Select your server you want to apply the args to
4. Select tab "Server Start" under "Configuration" tab
5. Edit "Arguments" box